# DataTables "sticky" table headers for a Drupal view

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, datatables

How to display the table's header and / or footer fixed to the top or bottom of the scrolling window? I used [datatables module](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) with Drupal 7, but the module does not offers an option to make table's header sticky. This page was also helpful (https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/) but I could not get the code to work on my custom js file.

```
var table = $('#datatable-1').DataTable();

new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table, {
    bottom: true
} );
```

Comment: I don't know how drupal modules work, but FixedHeader is a separate plugin from datatables, normally you have to install it separately

Comment: yes, I did installed plugin separately but was unable to make it works.

Comment: I switched back to bootstrap tables until I have time to test datatables plugins.